# How much damage do you take when failing a hack?

Tags: nier-automata

While playing as 9S, you have the option to hack and enemy as an attack. If you succeed in the hack, you will do damage or kill the enemies. However if you fail the hack, you take damage. Is the damage you take always the same or is it dependent on several factors?

Comment: Give me like an hour. I did a test on this a while ago so I've got pictures, but I'm at work atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will always take a set amount of damage when you fail a hack. I tested this on an easy Amusement Park enemy and on the Golden Bunny statue. Both dealt the same amount of damage:

[image: regular enemy]

[image: golden bunny statue]

In both of these images, I took 1738 damage. As you can see below, my total maximum health at the time was 8693.

[image: stats]

The total percentage of my health that this amount is is calculated below:

> 1738 / 8693 = 0.19993

So roughly 20% of my health.

I also tested this on Hard and Very Hard. You actually don't die if you fail a hack on Very Hard, contrary to my expectations. The amount of damage I took was 2173 out of 10868.

[image: damage taken on hard]

> 2173 / 10868 = 0.19994

So, again, roughly 20% of my health.

I allowed myself to fail two consecutive hacks and both times, I took 2173 damage, so failing multiple hacks does not affect damage taken.

---

Therefore, regardless of enemy or difficulty, you will take very slightly under 20% of your max health in damage if you fail a hack as 9S.

Comment: If you fail multiple hacks in a row, do you know if it increases the amount of damage that you take?

Comment: I just checked and multiple failed hacks does not affect damage taken.