# Nier Automata - 9S Hacking Base Damage (With No Hacking Chips Factored)

Tags: nier-automata

I am trying to figure out what factors attribute to the base damage when hacking with 9S ignoring any additional damage that is attributed to +Combust chips (thus base damange). This would be explicit to such cases where a single hack does not destroy the enemy. Take, for example, the Special Rank Gambler's Colosseum located in the Flooded Coast area. Most of the combatants require more than a single hack to destroy. Is there a damage value that can be reached through some formula or just a set arbitrary value that was assigned to the encounter respective to the story?

There was a very helpful post here about the damage 9S takes when failing a hack that I found to be rather informative, but does not actually help to answer my own question aside from coming to the conclusion that the Special Rank Colosseum battles deviate from the typical in game mechanics.

[Nier Automata - How much damage do you take when failing a hack?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/311017/how-much-damage-do-you-take-when-failing-a-hack/311028#311028?newreg=86b7beee7cd24d41b187145528b2e927)

What I find to be interesting is that the player to submit the answer failed hacks on both a grunt mob and a boss mob from a general area in the game and found the hack failure penalty to be about 20% of Max Health and found that multiple hack failures did not add additional penalty to the damage. That being said, I can tell you that failing a hack in the Special Rank Gamblers Colosseum does not follow this metric and leaves me with limping, greyscaled and frantic to jump back in to a new hack.

I'm just curious if anyone knows if it's possible to increase your base hack damage and what chips, aside from Combust, would be responsible for the increase.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit I am including my current chipset for 9S that I am using for above mentioned Special Rank Event.  There is no need to add additional Combust chips as 2x lvl 1 chips already meets cap.

[image]